# Coordinates in paint

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint

When you click in a box, it should create a circle in that box from the designated coordinate. Unless if its already there then its removed. How do I get currentx and currenty coordinates into the fill oval?

```
public class Grid extends Applet{

boolean click;

public void init()
{
    click = false;
    addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);

    g.drawRect(100, 100, 400, 400);
    //each box
    g.drawRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(200, 100, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(300, 100, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(400, 100, 100, 100);
    //2y
    g.drawRect(100, 200, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(200, 200, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(300, 200, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(400, 200, 100, 100);
    //3y1x
    g.drawRect(100, 300, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(200, 300, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(300, 300, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(400, 300, 100, 100);
    //4y1x
    g.drawRect(100, 400, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(200, 400, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(300, 400, 100, 100);
    g.drawRect(400, 400, 100, 100);


    if (click)
    {
        g.fillOval(currentx, currenty, 100, 100); // problem HERE
    }

}
private class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener
{       
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
         {
             int nowx = e.getX();
             int nowy = e.getY();

             nowx = nowx / 100;
             String stringx = Integer.toString(nowx);
             stringx = stringx+"00";
             int currentx = Integer.parseInt(stringx);

             nowy = nowy /100;
             String stringy = Integer.toString(nowy);
             stringy = stringy+"00";
             int currenty = Integer.parseInt(stringy);

             click = true;
             repaint();
         }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
}
```

Comment: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is, painting in Swing/AWT is destructive, that is, each time your `paint` method is called, you are expected to repaint the current state of the component.

In that case, what you really need is some way to model the state of the game so when `paint` is called, you can repaint it in some meaningful way.  This a basic concept of a [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm, where you separate the responsibility of the program into separate layers.

The problem then becomes, how do you translate from the view to model?

The basic idea is take the current x/y coordinates of the mouse and divide it by the cell size.  You also need to ensure that the results are within the expected ranges, as you could get a result which is beyond the columns/rows of grids

[image: Crosses]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final int CELL_COUNT = 3;

        private int[][] board;
        private int[] cell;

        private boolean isX = true;

        public TestPane() {
            board = new int[CELL_COUNT][CELL_COUNT];

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    int[] cell = getCellAt(e.getPoint());
                    if (board[cell[0]][cell[1]] == 0) {
                        board[cell[0]][cell[1]] = isX ? 1 : 2;
                        isX = !isX;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    cell = getCellAt(e.getPoint());
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        protected int[] getCellAt(Point p) {
            Point offset = getOffset();
            int cellSize = getCellSize();

            int x = p.x - offset.x;
            int y = p.y - offset.y;

            int gridx = Math.min(Math.max(0, x / cellSize), CELL_COUNT - 1);
            int gridy = Math.min(Math.max(0, y / cellSize), CELL_COUNT - 1);

            return new int[]{gridx, gridy};
        }

        protected Point getOffset() {
            int cellSize = getCellSize();
            int x = (getWidth() - (cellSize * CELL_COUNT)) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - (cellSize * CELL_COUNT)) / 2;
            return new Point(x, y);
        }

        protected int getCellSize() {
            return Math.min(getWidth() / CELL_COUNT, getHeight() / CELL_COUNT) - 10;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            Point offset = getOffset();
            int cellSize = getCellSize();
            if (cell != null) {
                g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 255, 128));
                g2d.fillRect(
                        offset.x + (cellSize * cell[0]),
                        offset.y + (cellSize * cell[1]),
                        cellSize,
                        cellSize);
            }

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            for (int col = 0; col < CELL_COUNT; col++) {
                for (int row = 0; row < CELL_COUNT; row++) {
                    int value = board[col][row];
                    int x = offset.x + (cellSize * col);
                    int y = offset.y + (cellSize * row);
                    String text = "";
                    switch (value) {
                        case 1:
                            text = "X";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            text = "O";
                            break;
                    }
                    x = x + ((cellSize - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2);
                    y = y + ((cellSize - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
                    g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
                }
            }

            int x = offset.x;
            int y = offset.y;
            for (int col = 1; col < CELL_COUNT; col++) {
                x = offset.x + (col * cellSize);
                g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y + (cellSize * CELL_COUNT));
            }
            x = offset.x;
            for (int row = 1; row < CELL_COUNT; row++) {
                y = offset.x + (row * cellSize);
                g2d.drawLine(x, y, x + (cellSize * CELL_COUNT), y);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you want to truncate a number to the nearest 100, e.g. 142 becomes 100, all you have to do is:

```
num = (num/100)*100;
```

this is because when you divide 2 integers it automatically truncates it, and you can just multiply it back to get the number. And what I think you want in this case is to create some field variables and some accessor methods. At the top of your MouseListener class, you will need to add:

```
private int mouseX=0;
private int mouseY=0;
```

then to be able to access these variables from outside of the mouselistener class you will need to add accessor methods:

```
public int getMouseX(){
    return mouseX;
}
```

in your Grid Class, you can add the field:

```
private MyMouseListener listener;
```

and then initialize it in your init by doing:

```
listener = new MyMouseListener();
addMouseListener(listener);
```

then you can do the same for mouseY, and finally from your paint method you can then call:

```
int mouseX = listener.getMouseX();
int mouseY = listener.getMouseY();
```

and from there it is as simple as doing [if statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) or [switch statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) to find which box you clicked in!

Comment: Why are you recommending that the original poster break OOP rules and use static fields and methods when this does not appear necessary nor beneficial?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels There are ways to do this involving OOP, but I wasn't sure the OP needed that, I will change it to fit OOP though